# Range of function $f(x) = x-\sqrt{(1-x^2 )}$

Tags: functions

> How can i find range of this function?
>   $$f(x) = x-\sqrt{1-x^2}$$

I know how to find range of $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ but that function is different. Can anyone help?

Comment: According to the graph, the range can not be more than one

Comment: Set $x=\sin\theta$ to end up with $\sin\theta-\cos\theta=\sqrt{2}\sin\left(\theta-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$. Now it is trivial that the range is a subset of $[-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}]$. Since $x$ ranges over $[-1,1]$ we have that $\theta$ ranges over $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ and the function ranges over $[-\sqrt{2},1]$.

Comment: @  Jack D'Aurizio . thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the domain of this function is $[-1,1]$, you can parametrize with $x=\sin\theta,\enspace-\frac\pi 2\le\theta\le\frac\pi2$.  Then
$$x-\sqrt{1-x^2}=\sin\theta-\cos\theta= \sqrt2\sin \Bigl(\theta-\frac\pi4\Bigr).$$
Now on $\bigl[-\frac\pi 2,\frac\pi2\bigr]$, $\;\theta-\frac\pi4\in\bigl[-\frac{3\pi}4,\frac\pi4\bigr] $, so
$$-1\le\sin \Bigl(\theta-\frac\pi4\Bigr)\le \frac{\sqrt2}2,\enspace\text{hence}\enspace -\sqrt 2\le f(x)\le 1.$$

Comment: thanks man. you are  genius

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach (to the ones already outlined in the comments or the other answers): on $[-1,1]$ both $x$ and $-\sqrt{1-x^2}$ are convex functions, so it is their sum. In particular the maximum value of $f(x)=x-\sqrt{1-x^2}$ is attained at one of the endpoints of $[-1,1]$, namely the right one. $f'(x)=0$ has a unique solution in $[-1,1]$, at $x=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, hence $f\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)=-\sqrt{2}$ is the minimum of the range of $f$.